# Do Mormons believe that all spirits are omnipresent?

Tags: lds, spirit, pneumatology, omniprescence

Are all spirits omnipresent? According to Mormon doctrine, God is [omnipresent](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/gs/omnipresent?lang=eng) through his spirit, does that mean that all spirits are omnipresent or is the Holy Ghost a special case?

Comment: Question number 6,000! For some reason I think that's kind of a big deal...

Comment: Where do you see that? Looks like 34158 to me.

Comment: On the [Questions page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions). When my question was at the top of the newest questions page the number on the top right said 6,000 questions. I'm not sure what the number in the url is representative of.

Comment: @ShemSeger if you are asking for LDS answers please put it in the question body; tags aren't always very noticeable.

Comment: @curiousdannii There's no guarantee that there is an LDS answer. With questions like these the LDS answer is often, *"It has not been revealed."* I put the tag there to indicate my preferred dogma, but if the question is unanswerable from an LDS perspective then I appreciate having answers from other traditions to provoke thought.

Comment: Too bad it's off-topic.

Comment: Don't mormons believe that humans and animals have spirits? Humans and animals are most assuredly not omni-present... I suppose one could argue that their spirits are somehow omnipresent, but not aware of it... but that's not a very meaningful sense of omnipresence...

Comment: Yes, Mormons also believe God is a physical resurrected being, his body and spirit are inseparable, and a physical being can only be in one place at one time. This is why the role of the Holy Ghost is essential. Out of the Godhead, only the Holy ghost can communicate with our spirits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LDS commentary on this question is sparse, but based on the below information I infer that the answer is no.

> “The Holy Ghost as a personage of Spirit can no more be omnipresent in
>   person than can the Father or the Son, but by his intelligence, his
>   knowledge, his power and influence, over and through the laws of
>   nature, he is and can be omnipresent throughout all the works of God
>   [(Joseph F. Smith, Gospel Doctrine, 61)](http://archive.org/stream/gospeldoctrine009956mbp/gospeldoctrine009956mbp_djvu.txt)

In other words, *presence* is related to knowledge, power, and influence over and through the laws of nature. These are areas where other spirits are deficient.

> Each spirit child of Heavenly Father differs in intelligence. Jesus
>   Christ is more intelligent than all of Heavenly Father’s spirit
>   children, and His wisdom excels them all. [The Pearl of Great Price: Teacher Manual, (2000), 44–46](https://www.lds.org/manual/the-pearl-of-great-price-teacher-manual/the-book-of-abraham/abraham-318-28-the-lord-taught-abraham-about-the-premortal-existence?lang=eng)

Because other spirits don't have the perfect intelligence, knowledge, power, and influence of the Holy Ghost, they probably can't have omnipresence either.

Comment: Small addition: In D&C 130, I think (or somewhere close), it is explicitly stated that there is no such thing as "immaterial" matter, and that "spirit" is really just a type of "matter" that we can't sense. Possibly relevant to the subject (and an even better source than any manual can ever be). Also potentially relevant, but maybe a little more open to argument, is a scripture in 1 Nephi 10 (I think), where Nephi talks to "the spirit of the Lord", and realizes that he has the form of a man. It is of course not entirely clear if that is supposed to be the Holy Ghost, but I always assumed it is